# What is "isometric activation"?

Tags: word-meaning

What is ["isometric activation"](https://youtu.be/Ux4fqfmzh4E)? I did check a dictionary, it didn't make things more clear to me

> Because we add this **isometric** contraction, we're squeezing the dumbbell as hard as we possibly can, we're activating the chest **isometrically**.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It means contacting the muscle without moving. The classic example is the contraction of the core muscles during a plank. In a plank, your body isn't moving, but you still need to activate your core muscles to hold your body straight. This is probably not a term most people are familiar with, except for people who spend time learning about exercise/fitness.

You can read more on [Wikipedia.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isometric_exercise)